# How can I check if a lost Android phone has been flashed

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, bootloader, oneplus-3

My wife lost her OnePlus 3T and after 4 days it's returned by a passerby who found it.

Not to sound paranoid, but is it possible the phone was flashed with custom ROM but retains all the data? Can someone be possibly stealing data / eavesdropping on the phone this way?

If I go to about device Android version, kernel version etc still shows the same information.

Is there any checks I should perform to detect any other malicious activity?

Comment: Honestly, someone with a very high skill level may be able to add applications to steal data or information without your knowledge and without being easily detectable without someone of significant knowledge, but honestly what are the chances? Someone with that high a skill level could get everything they want from the device, wipe it and sell it for a double payoff on a single device. The possibility they would go through that trouble and return the device are near zero, unless your wife is a high level politician, celebrity, or other "person of interest". Just feel lucky it was returned.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the same information about your phone and all the things are just like before, its ok.

(stolen) The possibility is: if you had not security like lockscreen, then it's biggest. but, if not, the way to do it is hard to do and to take it easy the phone should be with OEM-on and some things more.
You can check (by active Developer Mode) if your device is 'Allow OEM', and look the system apps, if there's someone 'strange'.
However, you can get backup your files and reset the phone to get safe over that.

I hope it help you.

Comment: Good pointer to "Allow OEM unlocking", I didn't think of that. But can that not be toggled back again after flashing (and maybe relocking the bootloader)? After all, it shows a toggle (and not a fuse). If someone takes such good care to camouflage that even the section in "about phone" looks identical, I'd trust that someone to switch this toggle back, too. But yeah: with a password lock in place, the entire process would have been almost impossible to start with (too much trouble to be "worth the fun").